# Get Itunes Notification after syncing with iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications, itunes

My app has a feature for File Sharing through iTunes, and I want to get a notification/a method call after the process of syncing with iTunes is finished, so that I can reload my Table View with new data from iTunes. I have tried to override `- (void)viewWillAppear:` but it doesn't seem to run. Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The method

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

will be called after the iTunes syncing process. I just need to overwrite it and fill in the refresh methods